# Multi-language support with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to use GatsbyJS static site generator to rewrite my site.
User can change language via UI.
There are few folders with localized text data:

`- src 
  - data
    - en
      - text1.json
      - text2.json
        ...
    - de
      - text1.json
      - text2.json
        ...
    - es
      - text1.json
      - text2.json
        ...`

How can I get data according to the current language? 
How should the GraphQL query look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the community [gatsby-plugin-i18n](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n).

You can found an example using markdownRemark configuration:

```
// Add to gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-i18n',
      options: {        
        langKeyDefault: 'en',
        useLangKeyLayout: false,
        markdownRemark: {
          postPage: 'src/templates/blog-post.js',
          query: `
          {
            allMarkdownRemark {
                edges {
                  node {
                    fields {
                      slug,
                      langKey,
                    }
                  }
                }
             }
          }
          `
        }
      }
    }
]
```

You will probably want to filter your graphql query according to the `langKey` value:

```
allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fields: { langKey: { eq: "en" } } }) {
  edges {
    node {
      fields {
        slug,
        langKey,
        #your data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looking at the [showcase](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n#showcase) sources could help you too.